# Bootstrap nav-tabs not displaying tab-content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am looping through an object passed to the View (I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3) and creating a Nav Tab using Bootstrap.

At the moment, the actual TABS work and render fine. The **tab-content** however doesn't get displayed - Or one of them will if I make it's class "active" which basically shows the current tab-content (It doesn't change when I click on a different tab).

**What I want to happen:** Click on a tab -> It's content appears.

**What currently happens:** Click on a tab -> Nothing shows unless I change a tab-content's class to active (like i mentioned earlier).

Below is my code:

```
<div>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    @for (int i = 0; i < 1; )
    {
        foreach (var cat in Model.MyObject)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                <li class="active"><a href="#@cat.Name" data-toggle="tab">@cat.Name</a></li>
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                <li><a href="#@cat.Name" data-toggle="tab">@cat.Name</a></li>
            }
        }
    }

</ul>
<div class="tab-content" style="overflow: visible;">
    @for (int i = 0; i < 1; )
    {
        foreach (var cat in Model.Model.MyObject)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="#@cat.Name">@cat.Name</div>
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                <div class="tab-pane" id="#@cat.Name">@cat.Name</div>
            }
        }
    }
</div>
```

I put a Breakpoint over each foreach loop - there IS content being passed so that's **not** the problem.

How do I modify the code so the content changes when I select a different tab?

**EDIT:** I have made an IF function that only makes the first one active. As of now, the tabs can switch, BUT, the contents DON'T switch. Only the first content is shown and it won't change even if I click on another tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a similar thing in cakePHP. You need to specify one of them as `active` so that when the user loads the page they see the active tab. Then when they click on a different tab the js kicks in and moves the `active` class to that tab. You can put an `if` statement in to have it only add the `active` class to the first tab (or whichever tab you want active by default).

Comment: Hi. Please check my original post. I have updated it. My system now only shows 1 content and it doesn't switch when I hit another tab. Please help...

Comment: Are you including jquery.js somewhere before your bootstrap.js? Most of the functions in the Javascript section require jquery. I believe if jquery is not present or is after bootstrap.js you will see the tabs change but not the content.

Comment: Yes I am: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>

Comment: Oh i see your problem... Sorry it wasn't the .js files. You have `id="#@cat.Name"` in your tab content. The ID should not have the `#`. The href in the tab does keep that though.

Comment: Thank you so so so so so so much. I love you. I really really love you. Truly love you. I love you! I LOVE YOU MAN! :'(

Answer (score 2):

You have the markup, but not the logic for `active` class. Bootstrap provides that logic through Javascript.

```
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
})
```

Source: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs

Comment: Can you share yout JS? Maybe a jsfiddle?

Comment: The JS isn't the problem. The Tabbing works fine. I implemented hard-coded components and they work perfectly. But this "dynamic" code doesn't seem to work properly. Right now, the code only shows 1 content and it doesn't switch when I hit the tabs. the tabs however DO switch nicely.